# Add 'Online Users' area

Tags: php, sql

How would I add an area that shows which users are online until they leave the page or log out?

I thought about making a table that keeps the users session until they leave the page, but how would I be able to tell when they left? I only need it to be updated maybe every 5 seconds. I want to stay away from cron jobs just in case of windows, (windows doesn't support cron does it?)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I did similar thing in one of our applications some time ago. Bind an Ajax call to some event like click or mousemove. In that call write the timestamp to the active_users table. Write another function to query this table and select users with timestamp older than say 5 min. Call this via Ajax as well in specific time intervals or on broeser event.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions to it and you should probably post some code for your implementation if you want code back.

As an overall design question, you would probably need a means for storing how many users are online (more on detecting that below) either in memory (backend service, in memory DB like redis or memcached) or on disk (regular DB).

As for detecting when users are online, it can be a fairly difficult problem, but assuming that exact up to the second numbers don't matter that much, you could increment the number (in the DB or memory from above) when you serve the page (PHP) or when the user loads the page (Javascript).

As for detecting when a user has navigated away, you could use an `onunload` handler in Javascript such that it notifies the server when the user navigates away.  One caveat to watch out for is that this message could get lost or not be sent (ie. JS off, browser crash, etc.) and your count could become wildly inaccurate.

Alternatively, the client can ping the server with a heartbeat every `[predefined interval]`  and the server would know they are online (decrementing the counter when the user stops sending the heartbeat, assuming they have navigated away)

Based on these high level solutions, they could also be combined to form a hybrid solution, using heartbeats to detect that users are still online and an `onunload` handler to notify the server right away on close/navigation.

Finally, just as a note about cron jobs, Windows doesn't have `cron` per se but can accomplish a similar goal using Scheduled Tasks.

Comment: Is there a database setting that will remove them after x minutes if it hasn't been updated within x minutes

Comment: Or could you point me in the right direction for the heartbeat idea?

Comment: refer to my answer to see how I did it

Comment: @Cheesecake That will depend on what database you're using. [Richard-Rodriguez's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27074133/1059070) has an implementation of the heartbeat idea.

Comment: I added what I did but I can't accept it for another four hours

Comment: Ok, well glad to hear we were able to help. You should also upvote (up arrow) all the answers that helped as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are various options. Here is the one I prefer, but your mileage may vary.

Use JavaScript to ask your users to poll/bump your server once in a while and use this request to store which users are online. An example of the JavaScript part using jQuery:

```
var ajaxCall;
var livedataTimer;
function poll(timeout){
   livedataTimer = setTimeout(function(){
      if (ajaxCall != null){
         ajaxCall.abort();
      }
      if (timeout == 5){
         timeout = 10000;
      }
      ajaxCall = $.ajax({ url: '/ajax/bump.php', type: 'POST', success: function(data){
         poll(timeout);
      }, dataType: "json"});
   }, timeout);
   return livedataTimer;
}
```

An example of the `/ajax/bump.php` file:

```
<?php

session_start(); ## to know which user is online

## connect to your DB somewhere

mysqli_query($connection,"
   INSERT INTO `online-status`
   (`user`, `time`)
   VALUES
   (".(int)$_SESSION['user']['id'].", UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
");

return TRUE; ## return TRUE so that ajax knows the file has completed

?>
```

Now to get the list of online users, you can lookup your `online-status` table with a condition, for example, "where time is not older than 20 seconds."

It's a good practice to `INSERT` the data into a separate database, not `UPDATE` the timestamps in your `userlist` database. These tend to be quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `time();` function to insert a value into the users table every time a user visited a page, and pulled it out and and used this function,

```
        echo '<h3>Online Users</h3>';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        if(time() - 10 < $row['active']){
        echo '<a href="index.php?action=ucp&uid='.$row['uid'].'">'.$row['username'].'</a>';
        }
        }
```